# Making NSTextField not shrink when NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail is set

Tags: cocoa, nsattributedstring, nstextfield

The `NSTextField` shrinks slightly if `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` is set as the line break mode without adding ellipses. Can this be prevented somehow? In iOS you can do this but I can't find a way on the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Simply `setAllowsDefaultTighteningForTruncation` to YES on the `NSMutableParagraphStyle`